# SMD tactile switch with 4 pins extension

Tags: surface-mount

I have a problem, I have a row of 4 horizontal SMD tactile switches on a circuit board I want to mount them externally so I desoldered them and put 4 wires to each corner of each switch and resoldered the wires to the circuit board however when I press the switches they no longer work they only work when directly soldered to the circuit board.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Pictures .... ?

Comment: Hi sorry it's 5 switches if you go to this eBay link it's the controller at the bottom of the picture.http://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/LVDS-LCD-Controller-Board-Kit-DIY-HDMI-VGA-Driver-Board-HDMI-VGA-DVI-AUDIO-/111930025893?hash=item1a0f8ca7a5%3Ag%3AO4MAAOSwLnBXUmoY&_trkparms=pageci%253A0925d3e1-73a9-11e6-85d3-74dbd180197e%257Cparentrq%253Afc1508a61560a6a8c2080459fff76a63%257Ciid%253A4

Comment: They don't look very surface mount to me. Did you know you only need 2 wires per button, and you don't even need the PCB? You can just wire direct to the connector that the board plugs into. It looks (though it's hard to make out) like it even has the connector pinout on there for you.

Comment: Have you rotated them through 90 degrees by mistake?

Comment: If you go to the 4th picture of 5 on the link those are the switches I need to move, if I wire them off the board they longer work

Comment: Pictures .... ? **after your modifications**

Comment: I will have to get some and post them later all I did was use some thin wire between each corner of the switch and then soldered the wires between each corner of the switches, perhaps the wire is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you rotated the switches by 90 degrees.

Most tactile switches with 4 legs are constructed with two parallel busses, giving you 4 mounting points. The switch simply connects the busses together when pressed.

If you rotated the switch connections by 90 degrees, the circuit sees the switch as closed.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out, could it be possible I am not creating enough current for the switch to recognise sorry I don't know anything about electronics but I need to sort this thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Each side pair should be common and do not depend on PCB, but are extremely sensitive to excess solder temp with thin film membrane contacts.

Comment: I've found that this arrangement of legs allows them to be easily soldered to staples (yes, really, the stationery kind) so they can plug into breadboards. Or feet, if you tread on one. One staple per pair.